# How do I get my css modules to work properly in react.js?

Tags: reactjs

Im building a burger builder app from a udemy course and while the code works fine, Im recieving errors that the app failed to load a resource
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSowE.png)

im new to javascript and react and im still learning how to debug my code so I am also having trouble finding which component the problem is in my code.

Comment: May be it because of typo at `data.columns = [['data,','Open'...` it supposed to be `data.columns = [['Date,','Open'...`

Comment: I fixed that typo and im still getting the error message

Answer (score 0):

> data.columns needs to be a 1-D array, you've used a 2D array.

And you're also accessing data.Date - Date is a reserved word, so maybe use lowercase date (its actually data in columns so a bit confusing there).

Let me know if this fixes it.

Comment: I just made the changes and im still getting the same error